# Ruby on Rails Else If Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application where in the layout I have a user_name div which will display different things based on whether or not they are logged in, are an admin, etc. Right now my code is the following:

```
  <% if current_user.role == "admin" %>
  <p id="admintxt">You are an admin!</p>
      <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(:current) %>
   <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>
  <% elsif current_user %>
   <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(:current) %>
   <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>
  <% else %>
<%= link_to "Register", new_user_path %>
<%= link_to "Login", login_path %>
<% end %>
```

I have a current_user helper already and everything was working fine when the code was just:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(:current) %>
  <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Register", new_user_path %>
    <%= link_to "Login", login_path %>
<% end %>
```

Now when I make it an elsif statement, when I am logged in as an admin it works and I get the text displayed with the correct links. When I am not an admin user/logged out, I get a undefined method `role' for nil:NilClass error...  Also my current_user stuff is declared in my application controller as follows:

```
helper_method :current_user


private

def current_user_session
  return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
  @current_user_session = UserSession.find
end

def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
  @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
end
```

Any ideas what I can do to display the result I want? "If they are a user with the role attribute equal to admin they get some text and the logged in links, if they are just a user they get the logged in links, and if they are not logged in they get the register and login links.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

```
<% if current_user %>
  <% if current_user.role == "admin" %>
    <p id="admintxt">You are an admin!</p>
    <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(:current) %>
    <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(:current) %>
    <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Register", new_user_path %>
  <%= link_to "Login", login_path %>
<% end %>
```

or with Rails >= 2.3

```
<% if current_user.try(:role) == "admin" %>
  <p id="admintxt">You are an admin!</p>
  <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(:current) %>
  <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>
<% elsif current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(:current) %>
  <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Register", new_user_path %>
  <%= link_to "Login", login_path %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Looking at this makes me really appreciate haml. :)

Comment: I have been writing `erb` but never realized how ugly it is until I saw this. I now appreciate react

Answer (score 5):

Hide the role check in the current user loop, which has the side effect of simplifying your conditional.

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= content_tag(:p, "You are an admin!", :id=>"admintxt") if current_user.role == "admin" %>
  <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(:current) %>
  <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Register", new_user_path %>
  <%= link_to "Login", login_path %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, as I was writing the loop I knew there was definitely a way to simplify it. I am learning lots!

Answer (score 3):

```
<% if current_user and current_user.role == "admin" %>
```

This should prevent the error when there is no user logged in, but you could restructure the whole block in order to remove the redundant tests against current_user being nil.